# get .class file using tomcat7 user on ubuntu

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I want to compile a `java` file with `tomcat7` user on `ubuntu`.
Here, I will describe my context:

I have a web `tomcat application` (a simple page index.jsp),
In this page, I create a java file `Hello.java` into `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/Test` folder.

The file is created with the following properties:
`-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat7 tomcat7 235 déc. 21 19:27 Hello.java`

I want to compile this file using:`javac Hello.java`
but I have problem with permission.

I did a test changing the `user:group` to this java file,
for example, my `sudo` user on ubuntu is `home20`, so I did:
`sudo chown home20:home20 Hello.java`and I got:

`-rw-r--r-- 1 home20 home20 235 déc. 21 19:27 Hello.java`

And, I did: `javac Hello.java` and I generated `Hello.class`

I wanto to get `Hello.class` using tomcat7 user.

Would you have any idea?

Thanks in advance for your help and time.

Comment: Why do you change the permission of Hello.java to your Tomcat user??

Comment: Because this file is generated from index.jsp (tomcat application) and it is generated with tomcat7:tomcat7 permission.

Comment: Why don't you create the file in a folder where the tomcat7 user has executable (x) permissions ?

Comment: Thank Saif Asif. Yes, your idea is OK, it runs fine. I did: sudo chmod 777 -R myfolder/. I will continue with my app. and I will describe my results.

Comment: Yes, absolutely, I set executable permission to my folder and my java file can be built and run. [Step 1: sudo chmod 777 -R myfolder], [Step 2: javac Hello.java] and [Step 3: java Hello].